# Why casting division by zero to integer primitives gives different results?

Tags: java, casting, binary, primitive-types

```
    System.out.println((byte) (1.0/0));
    System.out.println((short) (1.0/0));
    System.out.println((int) (1.0/0));
    System.out.println((long) (1.0/0));
```

The result is:

```
    -1
    -1
    2147483647
    9223372036854775807
```

In binary format:

```
    1111 1111
    1111 1111 1111 1111
    0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
    0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

Why casting infinity to int and long integers keeps sign bit as "0", while sets sign bit to "1" for byte and short integers?

Comment: I assume it is casting to an `int` and then to a `byte` Note: Integer.MAX_VALUE is the closest value to Infinity for an `int`.

Comment: Thx Peter, but casting Integer.MAX_VALUE to 'long' would give us just '2147483647L', am I right?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Wouldn't it be possible for `(1.0/0)` to be evaluated as a `double`, and then the caste to byte consider the bottom 8 bits? While IEEE 754 defines the standard for `double` and `float`, I find it odd that the sign bit is 0 for `int` since the docs don't define infinity specs for `int`.

Comment: You don't cast `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to `long`. If the type is `long`, it chooses the maximum representable value in case of +Infinity which is `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does double to int cast work in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514958/how-does-double-to-int-cast-work-in-java)

Comment: @DebosmitRay the top bit is 0 for `int` the maximum representable value and when this is cast to short or byte, the top bit is `1`.

Comment: @Dragan Bozanovic - should I press button "That solved my problem" about the link you supplied? That Q is similar, but I couldn't find it more than hour searching...
Thx everyone, answered my Q very fast.

Comment: @AlexanderRadchenko It's up to you. You don't have to if you think that your question is not an exact duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[JLS 5.1.3:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)

> A narrowing conversion of a floating-point number to an integral type T takes two steps:
>
> In the first step, the floating-point number is converted either to a
>   long, if T is long, or to an int, if T is byte, short, char, or int,
>   as follows:
>
> If the floating-point number is NaN (§4.2.3), the result of the first
>   step of the conversion is an int or long 0.
>
> Otherwise, if the floating-point number is not an infinity, the
>   floating-point value is rounded to an integer value V, rounding toward
>   zero using IEEE 754 round-toward-zero mode (§4.2.3). Then there are
>   two cases:
>
> If T is long, and this integer value can be represented as a long,
>   then the result of the first step is the long value V.
>
> Otherwise, if this integer value can be represented as an int, then
>   the result of the first step is the int value V.
>
> Otherwise, one of the following two cases must be true:
>
> The value must be too small (a negative value of large magnitude or
>   negative infinity), and the result of the first step is the smallest
>   representable value of type int or long.
>
> **The value must be too large (a positive value of large magnitude or
>   positive infinity), and the result of the first step is the largest
>   representable value of type int or long.**
>
> In the second step:
>
> If T is int or long, the result of the conversion is the result of the
>   first step.
>
> **If T is byte, char, or short, the result of the conversion is the
>   result of a narrowing conversion to type T (§5.1.3) of the result of
>   the first step.**

So an infinite double value is first cast to `int` by returning `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, and *then* it is further cast to `byte`/`short`, which takes the appropriate number of low bytes (and gets -1 as a result).  Casts to `int` and `long` don't have that extra step, but `byte` and `short` go *first* through `int` and *then* to `byte`/`short`.

Comment: I was about to refer to Narrowing Primitive Conversion also! +1