# java testing if double is an int

Tags: java, int, double, equals-operator

Part of my program tests if two numbers are equal.  Because certain operations take only doubles and others take only ints, I am comparing ints and doubles.  The programs is returning that the two are equal even when they only *round* to being equal (i.e. `7.5=7`).  I only want the program to return true if the two actually *are* equal.  I've tried the solutions listed here: [How to test if a double is an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898512/how-to-test-if-a-double-is-an-integer)
to determine if my doubles are ints.
All of them appear to work - they compile, but the program still returns `7=7.5`
I've tried going the other direction also - converting my ints to doubles - same result.  How do I get my program to acknowledge the difference?  With the most current suggestion:

```
import acm.program.ConsoleProgram;
import java.awt.Color;
import  acm.io.IODialog;
import java.text.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;
import java.util.*;

/** Tests to see if user color matches sample colors */
public class ColorMatch extends ConsoleProgram
{
//defining sample colors
Color[] dmc =
{
    new Color(255,255,255),
    new Color(43,57,41),
    new Color(213,39,86),
    new Color(0,160,130),
    new Color(0,0,0),
};

public void run()
{
    average();

}

//averages three colors, then tests for match to given color
public void average()
{
    //asks for stitch color
    IODialog dialog     = new IODialog();
    int stitchRed       = dialog.readInt("Enter red value: ");
    int stitchGreen     = dialog.readInt("Enter green value: ");
    int stitchBlue      = dialog.readInt("Enter blue value: ");
    Color stitchColor   = new Color(stitchRed,stitchGreen,stitchBlue);

    //gets averages for dmc colors
    for (Color i:dmc)
    {
        for (Color j:dmc)
        {
            for (Color k:dmc)
            {
                int indexI = Arrays.asList(dmc).indexOf(i);
                int indexJ = Arrays.asList(dmc).indexOf(j);
                int indexK = Arrays.asList(dmc).indexOf(k);
                if  (indexI <= indexJ && indexJ <= indexK)
                {
                    int iRed = i.getRed();
                    int jRed = j.getRed();
                    int kRed = k.getRed();
                    int iGreen = i.getGreen();
                    int jGreen = j.getGreen();
                    int kGreen = k.getGreen();
                    int iBlue = i.getBlue();
                    int jBlue = j.getBlue();
                    int kBlue = k.getBlue();
                    double redAverage   = (iRed+jRed+kRed)/3;
                    double greenAverage = (iGreen+jGreen+kGreen)/3;
                    double blueAverage  = (iBlue+jBlue+kBlue)/3;
                    if (redAverage == (int)redAverage && greenAverage == (int)greenAverage && blueAverage == (int)blueAverage)
                    {
                        int rAverage = (int)redAverage;
                        int gAverage = (int)greenAverage;
                        int bAverage = (int)blueAverage;
                        Color colorAverage = new Color(rAverage,gAverage,bAverage);

                        //tests to see if any average equals the stitch color
                        if (colorAverage.equals(stitchColor))
                        {
                            println("The color match is: " + i + ", " + j + ", " + k);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I plugged in 85s as my test numbers.
The only result should be `(0,0,0)+(0,0,0)+(255,255,255)`, but it is also yielding `(43,57,41)+(213,39,86)+(0,160,130) . (41+86+130)/3=85.7!=85`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Also, try looking at this question for your issue with doubles and ints: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9898512/5335355

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are making a comparison of the 'int' and the 'double' values after casting the double value to int which truncates the decimal part.
For example `(7==7.5)` is **false**, but `(7==(int)7.5)` is **true** because `(int)7.5 = 7`.
So if you want strict comparison between an int and a double, you can compare them straight forward without casting. If you want to know more on how casting double to int works, please refer [How does double to int cast work in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514958/how-does-double-to-int-cast-work-in-java).

Comment: I'm comparing the double value: redAverage to the truncated integer of redAverage  If they are equal, then redAverage should be an int.  I have alternatively compared it using the floor function for redAverage.  I've also comared the floor and ceiling of redAverage.  I used the solutions listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898512/how-to-test-if-a-double-is-an-integer