# Which method is used in Kotlin's Double.toInt(), rounding or truncation?

Tags: type-conversion, kotlin

On [the official API doc](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-double/to-int.html), it says:

> Returns the value of this number as an Int, which may involve rounding or truncation.

I want truncation, but not sure. Can anyone explain the exact meaning of `may involve rounding or truncation`?

p.s.: In my unit test, `(1.7).toInt()` was 1, which **might** involve truncation.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The KDoc of `Double.toInt()` is simply inherited from [`Number.toInt()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-number/to-int.html), and for that, the exact meaning is, it is defined in the concrete `Number` implementation how it is converted to `Int`.

In Kotlin, the `Double` operations follow the IEEE 754 standard, and the semantics of the `Double.toInt()` conversion is the same as that of [casting `double` to `int` in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12515017/2196460), i.e. normal numbers are rounded toward zero, dropping the fractional part:

```
println(1.1.toInt())  // 1
println(1.7.toInt())  // 1
println(-2.3.toInt()) // -2
println(-2.9.toInt()) // -2
```

Comment: I only find an abstract `Number`, where is this concrete `Number`?

Comment: That's it, there is only one `Number`. The implementation mentioned in the answer is an intrinsic generated by kotlinc. Thus there is no virtual method you could look at.

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `to.Int()`, and send the value to the new variable which is marked as `Int`:

`val x: Int = variable_name.toInt()`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this documentation [is straight up copied](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#intValue--) from Java's documentation.

As far as I know it only truncates the decimal points, e.g. `3.14` will become `3`, `12.345` will become `12`, and `9.999` will become `9`.

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2143505/3533380) answer and the comments under it suggests that there is no actual rounding. The "rounding" is actually truncating. The rounding differs from `Math.floor` that instead of rounding to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` it rounds to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

use this roundToInt() in kotlin

```
import kotlin.math.roundToInt
fun main() {
    var r = 3.1416
    var c:Int =  r.roundToInt() 
    println(c)
}
```