# Loss of precision when casting Math.pow()

Tags: java, casting, int

I tried to calculate the maximum value of int, however I can not figure out why calculated value that is cast to int is lower than when cast to long. I raised `(2^31) - 1` on the calculator and the value is

```
2_147_483_647
```

and I would expect the same when I rise `2^31` and deduct `1` in Java, it should calculate maximum number for int `2147483647`, but it doesn't.

```
System.out.println(((long) Math.pow(2, 31)) - 1); 
System.out.println((int) Math.pow(2, 31) - 1);
```

The first calculation gives: `2_147_483_647`

Second calculation gives: `2_147_483_646`

Comment: Java doesn't overflow when casting double -> int and that's why the math doesn't check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First example

Let us analyze what you have done. The first example is

```
((long) Math.pow(2, 31)) - 1;
```

This means that you first compute `Math.pow(2, 31)` which yields

```
2.147_483_648 E9
```

After that you cast to `long`. Note that `long` has enough place for this value, so it represents it as

```
2_147_483_648
```

Then you subtract `1` and get

```
2_147_483_647
```

---

### Second example

Let's now see what the second example does. Your wrote

```
(int) Math.pow(2, 31) - 1
```

This is interpreted as

```
((int) Math.pow(2, 31)) - 1
```

So the same as before but with a cast to `int` instead of `long`. Now note that `int` does **not have enough place** for the value. The biggest `int` that can be represented is

```
2_147_483_647 // MAX_INTEGER
```

and thus you will also get exactly this value here. After that you subtract `1` and get

```
2_147_483_646
```

---

### Correction

I think you thought that

```
(int) Math.pow(2, 31) - 1
```

evaluates to

```
(int) (Math.pow(2, 31) - 1)
```

but it doesn't. If you make this explicit you will indeed get

```
2_147_483_647
```

as expected.

---

### Operator precedence

You can read about that in the **Java Language Specification**, refer to [JLS§15.15 Unary Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15). Casting has **precedence over** operators like subtraction.

That is because **casting** is an **unary operator** whereas subtraction is **binary**. Unary has precedence over binary. The [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) therefore gives the following table as overview:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Operators             | Precedence (top is high, bottom low)   |
|-----------------------|----------------------------------------|
| postfix               | expr++ expr--                          |
| unary                 | ++expr --expr +expr -expr ~ !          |
| multiplicative        | * / %                                  |
| additive              | + -                                    |
| shift                 | << >> >>>                              |
| relational            | < > <= >= instanceof                   |
| equality              | == !=                                  |
| bitwise AND           | &                                      |
| bitwise exclusive OR  | ^                                      |
| bitwise inclusive OR  | |                                      |
| logical AND           | &&                                     |
| logical OR            | ||                                     |
| ternary               | ? :                                    |
| assignment            | = += -= *= /= %= &= ^= |= <<= >>= >>>= |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Casting** is of course part of the **unary** category.

Answer (score 4):

A cast has precedence over subtraction. You should rather do the subtraction first:

```
 System.out.println((int) (Math.pow(2, 31) - 1));
```

- `Math.pow(2, 31)` is `2_147_483_648` with a type of `double` (since Math.pow() returns a double) , this number does not fit into an int.
- When you cast the double `2_147_483_648` to an int, it gets truncated to the largest value an int can hold (see [How does double to int cast work in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514958/how-does-double-to-int-cast-work-in-java)).
- The cast truncates the double `2_147_483_648` to the int `2_147_483_647`.
- Then your code subtracts 1, and ends up with   `2_147_483_646`.

Answer (score 1):

Typecast the whole `Math.pow(2, 31) - 1)`. Like this

```
System.out.println((int) (Math.pow(2, 31) - 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You put the brackets in the wrong place. It should be:

```
System.out.println((int) (Math.pow(2, 31) - 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing your code like this `(int) Math.pow(2, 31) - 1` makes Java cast `Math.pow(2, 31)` to int. Since that is more than the max value of int, it results to be `2_147_483_647`. Since you subtract 1 afterwards, you get a value lower than the actual solution.
You should rather cast the whole calculation to int than just `Math.pow(2, 31)` so it looks like this:
`(int) (Math.pow(2, 31) - 1)`