# Different outputs for Java and CPP

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, binary-search

I was solving [Nth root of M](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/find-nth-root-of-m5843/1#) problem and I solved it with Java and here is the solution:

```java
    public int NthRoot(int n, int m)
    {
        // code here
        int ans = -1;
        if (m == 0)
            return ans;
        if (n == 1 || n == 0)
            return m;
        if (m == 1)
            return 1;
        int low = 1;
        int high = m;
        while (low < high) {
            
            int mid = (low + high) / 2;
            int pow = (int)Math.pow(mid, n);
            if (pow == m) {
                
                ans = mid;
                break;
            }
            if (pow > m) {
                
                high = mid;
            } else {
                
                low = mid + 1;
            }
        }
        
        return ans;
    }
```

It passed all the test cases. But, when I solved it using C++, some test cases didn't pass. Here is the C++ solution:

```cpp
    int NthRoot(int n, int m)
    {
        // Code here.
        int ans = -1;
        if (m == 0)
            return ans;
        if (n == 1 || n == 0)
            return m;
        if (m == 1)
            return 1;
        int low = 1;
        int high = m;
        while (low < high) {
            
            int mid = (low + high) / 2;
            int po = (int)pow(mid, n);
            if (po == m) {
                
                ans = (int)mid;
                break;
            }
            if (po > m) {
                
                high = mid;
            } else {
                
                low = mid + 1;
            }
        }
        
        return ans;
    }
```

One of the test cases it didn't pass is:

```
6 4096
Java's output is 4 (Expected result)
C++'s output is -1 (Incorrect result)
```

When I traced it using paper and pen, I got a solution the same as Java's.

But, when I used `long long int` in the C++ code, it worked fine – but the size of `Int`/`int` in both Java and C++ are the same, right? (When I print `INT_MAX` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` in C++ and Java, it outputs the same value.)

Comment: Have you tried to *debug* the C++ program to see when and where it goes wrong? Also, without a proper [mcve] (to see how this function is called and with what arguments) it's impossible to say anything certain anyway.

Comment: By the way, `(int)mid`? If `mid` is a variable of type`int` there's no point in casting it to the same type.

Comment: "*But the size of Int in both Java and C++ are the same, right?*" - In Java, [`int`s are 32-bit integrals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). In C++, the size  of `int` is not determined in the language spec. Depending on different factors, it can be at least `16` or `32` bits. If you want a 32-bit signed integral number, use [`int32_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).

Comment: You could always try `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(int));` to double check that assumption.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude

`Line 17: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
        int num = Math.pow(5,2);`
When I use leetcode, it will throw an error like this since Math.pow returns double.

Comment: "But the size of Int in both Java and C++ are the same, right?". Wrong.

Comment: @Marivishnu C++ is not Java.  This is what happens when you attempt to translate line-by-line from Java to C++, without actually learning C++ proper.  Just because the languages look similar, there are vast differences, and you're running into those differences head-on.

Comment: I'm talking about `ans = (int)mid;` in the C++ code.

Comment: `(int)pow(mid, n);` -- That does not guarantee that you will get the result you're looking for.  The `pow` function is a floating point function, and there are instances where [pow() will not give the correct results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678481/why-does-pown-2-return-24-when-n-5-with-my-compiler-and-os/25678721#25678721).  Do not use floating point functions, variables, etc, if the problem can be solved using integer.

Comment: Have you ever checked what `std::pow(2048, 6)` returns and what the maximum value of your data type (`int`, `long long int`) is, and how c++ handles an overflow compared to java?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie 
https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_data_types.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_data_types.asp

When I checked these 2 pages, they showed that the size of int in both java and CPP are 4 bytes. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @Marivishnu No you are not correct.  Again, Java is not C++, and you're falling right into the trap.  Java has integer sizes that are fixed, C++ integer sizes depend on the implementation, but must have size guarantees relative to the various integer types (short, int, long, etc.).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah that's a mistake. I changed `ans` to `long long int` and I forgot to remove the casting after I changed it to int.

Comment: @Marivishnu w3schools always tend to be a bad source for information. [https://en.cppreference.com/](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) says that `int` is at least 16bit. So only a size of 2byte is guaranteed.

Comment: @Marivishnu -- Forget about using `long long int`.  If you want to *guarantee* that the integer type you're using is 32-bit or 64-bit, just like Java, use `int32_t` and `int64_t`, not `long long`, `long`, `int`, or some other type where the size is not readily known.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `Java has integer sizes that are fixed, C++ integer sizes depend on the implementation`
Ok thanks! Got it!

Comment: @t.niese `So only a size of 2byte is guaranteed` Ok! I will refer CPP reference. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `Forget about using long long int. If you want to guarantee that the integer type you're using is 32-bit or 64-bit, just like Java, use int32_t and int64_t, not long long, long, int, or some other type where the size is not readily known` 
Thanks! You really helped a lot! Thanks for your time

Comment: In addition to all the other problems, any C++ ***or Java*** program that uses `pow()` with two integer values, no matter what their size is, is automatically buggy, by default. This is because you'll be surprised to learn that `pow(5,2)` is not really 25. It is whatever `e^(2*log(5))` turns out to be, with rounding errors, et al. This is true for all programmig languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have probably guessed, the problem is due to the attempt to convert a `double` value to an `int` value, when that source is larger than the maximum representable value of an `int`. More specifically, it relates to the difference between how Java and C++ handle the cast near the start of your `while` loop: `int po = (int)pow(mid, n);`.

For your example input (`6 4096`), the value returned by the `pow` function on the first run through that loop is `7.3787e+19`, which is too big for an `int` value. In Java, when you attempt to cast a too-big value to an integer, the result is the maximum value representable by the integer type, as specified in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12515017/10871073) (bolding mine):

> - The value must be too large (a positive value of large magnitude or positive infinity), ***and the result of the first step is the largest
>   representable value of type int or long***.

However, in C++, when the source value exceeds `INT_MAX`, the behaviour is undefined (according to this [C++11 Draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf)):

> ##### 7.10 Floating-integral conversions      [conv.fpint]
>
> <sup>1</sup>    A prvalue of a floating-point
> type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion
> truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. The behavior is
> undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the
> destination type.

However, although formally undefined, many/most compilers/platforms will apply 'rollover' when this occurs, resulting in a very large **negative** value (typically, `INT_MIN`) for the result. This is what MSVC in Visual Studio does, giving a value of `-2147483648`, thus causing the `else` block to run … and *keep* running until the `while` loop reaches its terminating condition – at which point `ans` will never have been assigned any value except the initial `-1`.

You can fix the problem readily by checking the `double` returned by the `pow` call and setting `po` to `INT_MAX`, if appropriate, to emulate the Java bevahiour:

```cpp
    while (low < high) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        double fpo = pow(mid, n);
        int po = (int)(fpo);
        if (fpo > INT_MAX) po = INT_MAX; // Emulate Java for overflow
        if (po == m) {
            ans = (int)mid;
            break;
        }
        if (po > m) {
            high = mid;
        }
        else {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
    }
```