# Current value of a variable doesn't add up to previous value in a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, binary

```
    private void binary {
        String result = "11111111111111111111111111111000";
        int resultNum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
                int number = result.charAt(i) - '0';
                resultNum += number * Math.pow(2,(31 - i));
            }
        println("" + resultNum);
```

Each iteration of for loop assigns new value to resultNum and it overwrites previous one instead of adding to it. I don't understand why.

Comment: Does it work if you change `int resultNum = 0;` to `long resultNum = 0;` ?  Take a look at [Java Primitives page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), and pay attention to maximum value of `int`.

Comment: By the way, when a question is about a program that runs, but gives unexpected results, the code sample should compile cleanly.

Comment: _"assigns new value to resultNum "_ - How did you come to this conclusion?  `result` contains a 32-character string with a leading `1`, which actually represents a ***negative*** number.  Your code doesn't handle that condition, and as it stands will cause a (silent) numeric overflow, which probably explains what you are seeing.

Comment: Also, rather than using `Math.pow()` consider going right-to-left and using left-shift `<<` instead.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `Math.pow(2,(31 - i))` which results in a double value together with the rules for casting from double to int.

- `Math.pow(2, 30)` is 1073741824.0, casting that to an int is 1073741824 or 0x4000_0000 (as expected)
- `Math.pow(2, 31)` is 2147483648.0, casting that to an int is 2147483647 which is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or 0x7fff_ffff instead of possibly expected 0x8000_0000

The rules for the cast from double to int are explained in [How does double to int cast work in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514958/how-does-double-to-int-cast-work-in-java).

The first round in your loop already calculates `resultNum` as `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Any further computations in your loop calculate a double value greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` which when cast to an int is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` again.

To fix it don't use `Math.pow()`, use bit shifting instead:

```
resultNum += number << (31-i);
```